# Why does GCD backup & BQ load create RECORD with "string" and "provided" fields?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have half a dozen tables backing up and loading into BigQuery without any issues, but just one string field of dozens seems to translate into a RECORD field with with "string" and "provided" fields: [BQ table details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Zv5.png).

Why could this be? I'm not seeing these fields mentioned in my code in any way, and the backup & load jobs are all Google's code.

Comment: Please elaborate more and explain what kind of setup you have or give an example so we can fully understand your hassle.

Comment: clarified a little. figured out the solution, but was surprised this wasn't documented somewhere with the keywords in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when a String is long enough it gets stored as a [`Blob`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/entity-property-reference) in the datastore, and BigQuery does not support those, so they instead show up as base64encoded strings in the [GCD Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/query) and end up as:

```
{"d_3_string": null, "d_3_provided": null}
```

in BigQuery tables.